# how to open PDF file at specific page in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, pdf, adobe-reader, foxitreader

I am trying to open a .pdf file with FoxitReader from the terminal.

The following works on the terminal:

`/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader "Document.pdf"`

But this doesn't:

`/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader "Document.pdf /A page=5"`
It launches the FoxitReader GUI application, displaying "the file could not be found". The document has more than 5 pages.

- Foxit Reader version is 2.4.1.0609
- Ubuntu 16.04

is this option not available for linux systems? Did the syntax change? Do I need to install a plugin?

I also tried

```
/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader -h
/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader --help
```

but it fails to open these, too :(

**Edit**: 
I attempted the same in Adobe Acrobat Reader

```
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin/acroread /A "page=3" "Document.pdf"
```

with the same result. As always, instructions are documented for windows. I tried a couple of other PDF viewer now...

is there any free PDF reader able to:

- run in linux
- open PDF at a specific page
- highlight text
- display page in full view (optional)

?

thank you

Comment: evince -i 5 "Document.pdf" works

Comment: okular -p 5 "Document.pdf" works

Comment: Hello. Please add those as an answer below. You can edit your answer later if you discover new ways of doing it. After a while, you'll be able to accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it, which can be yours if you want.

Comment: aww, God, the option is ***lowercase*** for linux instead of uppercase. This is **NOT** according to the documentation. That settles it for Acrobat, Foxit's still refusing to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evince is a PDF viewer able to open PDF files at a specific page using the terminal with the following command:

```
evince -i 5 "path/to/document.pdf"
```

where `-i` option specifies the page of the document, 5 in this example, and the second argument specifies the path to the document to open.

Okular is a PDF viewer able to open PDF files at a specific page using the terminal with the following command:

```
okular -p 5 "path/to/document.pdf"
```

where `-p` option specifies the page of the document, 5 in this example, and the second argument specifies the path to the document to open.

Acrobate Reader is a PDF viewer able to open PDF files at a specific page using the terminal with the following command:

```
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin/acroread /a "page=5" "path/to/document.pdf"
```

where `page=5` is the argument that specifies the page of the document, 5 in this example, and the second argument specifies the path to the document to open.

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox PDF viewer will open at a page number by appending `#page=` followed by the page number to the URL, for example

```
firefox "file://$PWD/myfile.pdf#page=150"
```

The quotes are necessary if there is a space in your current path name. I like to use symbolic links and this won't work from the shell if the file is a symbolic link, but this does

```
firefox "file://$(realpath myfile.pdf)#page=150"
```